# Meteor CollectionFs - download button don't works

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple tickets app. When I create a new ticket, I can add attached file related to this one.
Download button don't works. Files metadata was correctly inserted into collection and I see it. Maybe, this is the reason: resources is not in the upload folder. I use the cfs:filesystem connector and here my code:

**ticket.html**

```
<head>
  <title>orangeticket-test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Tickets</h1>
  {{> newTickets}}
  {{> tickets}}
</body>

<template name="newTickets">
  <input type="text" id="ticket" placeholder="name" >
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</template>

<template name="tickets">
    {{#each tickets}}
      <div class="tickets">
          <p>Titolo: {{name}}</p>
      {{> addFile}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="addFile">
    <form>
        <input id="file" type="file">
        <input id="addFile" type="submit">
    </form>
    {{#each files}}
        <div class="file">
            <strong>{{this.name}}</strong> <a href="{{this.url download=true}}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**tickets.js**

```
Tickets = new Meteor.Collection('Tickets');

var fileStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("fileStore", {
  path: "~/uploads/files"
});
Files = new FS.Collection("Files", {
  stores: [fileStore]
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.tickets.helpers({
    tickets: function () {
      return Tickets.find();
    }
  });

  Template.newTickets.events({
    'click #submit': function (e, t) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var ticket = t.find('#ticket').value;
      Tickets.insert({name:ticket});
    }

  });

  Template.addFile.events({
    'click #addFile' : function(e, t){
      var file = t.find('#file').files[0];
      var ticket = this._id;
      var newFile = new FS.File(file);
      newFile.metadata = {
        ticketId: ticket
      };
      Files.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(fileObj);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  Template.addFile.helpers({
    files: function() {
      var ticket = this._id;
      return Files.find({'metadata.ticketId':ticket});
    }
  })
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log('server works');
  });
}
```

clone git project:

git@gitlab.com:arcidiaco.a/orangeticket-test.git

thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem right now!

Comment: I have tried many times and randomly only one attachment was uploaded correctly..I have also tried cfs:ui but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: the submit button refresh the page while file was uploaded. This action interrupt the upload action. I deleted submit button and used instead only file input with change event:

```
Template.addFile.events({
    'canche #file' : function(e, t){
      var file = t.find('#file').files[0];
      var ticket = this._id;
      var newFile = new FS.File(file);
      newFile.metadata = {
        ticketId: ticket
      };
      Files.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(fileObj);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```